# The size of the array should always be _

Tags: arrays, size

**Question:**
The size of the array should always be ___.
A Positive Number.
B Negative Number.
C Whole Number.
D Real Number.

ANS: A(IN all website)

Array size can be zero. So, whole number are the number will start from zero.
Why it is not a correction option

Answer (score 0):

A valid array in one such array that is not NULL. Hence, as an empty array can be termed as a NULL array, we need at least one element in the array - making its size > 0. Thus positive numbers only - as per the information provided by you.

Comment: This is more like a comment on the question rather than a solid answer. Please take a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297066/meta-meta-stack-overflow-when-should-i-answer-or-comment